# Exporting polygon shapefile to KML with polygon fill and line stroke symbology

Tags: qgis, polygon, export, kml, fill

I am running QGIS 3.16.10. I need to export several polygon shapefiles to KML with their polygon fill and line stroke symbology. I have done this before in earlier versions of QGIS but I can't seem to do it in 3.16.10?

Only the polygon outlines are exporting to KML and not the polygon transparent fills. Is this a bug or it there a way to do this?

Comment: As a workaround maybe you can try the MMQGIS plugin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfQQONQQ5TM

Comment: To my knowledge you need to style the KML using GE afterwards.

Comment: Give a try to the "KML Tools" Plugin, I find it easy to use.